# Beginning Silverlight 4. How to start?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did you learn/Best Way to learn Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283994/how-did-you-learn-best-way-to-learn-silverlight)

I am begginer in silverlight. Anyone suggest me the quicker way to learn silverlight or recommend any book or any other study material.

Comment: Please see this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283994/how-did-you-learn-best-way-to-learn-silverlight

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966460/how-to-learn-silverlight-4-0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012204/what-is-best-way-to-learn-silverlight, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527691/how-to-learn-silverlight-fastand many other posts like those in SO

Answer (score 1):

The official MS site has several good tutorials. You'll also want a copy of Expression Blend, and don't forget about the SDK.

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/